# Aligning top of text with background image in list items

Tags: css

I'm trying to set the text in [my list items here in the left nav](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/advertise.html) to be at the top of each image whehter single or double line, but can't get it to work correctly.

Here's the css and an example background image li:

```
.benefits li 
{font-size: 16px;
padding-left: 25px;
line-height: 2.1;
}

li.social {
background:url("/images/users.png") 0% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: So change the `50%` to `0`, then it'll be in the top-left. Or adjust the number to give an appropriate padding.

Comment: You should provide an HTML fragment. The correct answer depends on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `li` tag CSS to:

```
url("/images/megaphone.png") 0% 0% no-repeat;
```

That would be 50% to 0%.

Or, something like `0.4em` so the icon lines up nicer with the text.

```
url("/images/megaphone.png") 0% .4em no-repeat;
```

Comment: Thanks all for the replies.  Yeah I did think that, so don't know why I thought there'd be another way! Sounds silly, I'm tired I guess. They're both right..